# how to load the data from local system to hdfs using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a csv file `sample.csv` and located in `\home\hadoop\Desktop\script\sample.csv` .
I tried to load in PIG using

```
movies = load '/home/hadoop/Desktop/script/sample.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id,name,year,rating,duration);
```

But this PIG statement is giving an error but while giving statement as `dump movies;`, it is throwing error and showing input and output is failed.

Please suggest me how to load the data using pig statement.

Comment: Can you instead load it to HDFS first?

Comment: i am trying to load the file using PIG statement.

Comment: Pig runs on the worker nodes of the cluster so there is no single local filesystem. If you only have one node then you might have luck by doing something like: 'file:///home/hadoop/Desktop/script/sample.csv', but it won't work on a multi-node cluster.

Comment: I run pig in mapreduce mode.i have pseduo setup mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input file is at local then you can enter into grunt shell by typing      pig -x local

If you  enter into grunt shell then you can type the below statement

```
 record = LOAD  '/home/hadoop/Desktop/script/sample.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,year:chararray,rating:chararray,duration:int); 


dump record;
```

If your input file is not at local then first you need to copy that file from local to HDFS using below command

```
hadoop dfs -put <path of file at local>  <path of hdfs dir>
```

Once your file is loaded into HDFS you can enter to map reduce mode by typing pig

again grunt shell will be opened. ia assuming that your HDFS location is something like below LOAD statement

```
record = LOAD  '/user/hadoop/inputfiles/sample.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,year:chararray,rating:chararray,duration:int); 


dump record;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use copyFromLocal command in grunt shell to move local file to hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

open pig shell in local mode by `pig -x local` and if your file present at hdfs then you can use `pig` to open grant shell.

```
$pig -x local
grunt> movies = load '/home/hadoop/Desktop/script/sample.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,year:chararray,rating:chararray,duration:chararray);


grunt> dump movies;
```